# Android clock sync with Windows

Tags: android, windows, ntp

There are two parts to this question.

1. How do I sync the android clock with the Windows clock? I downloaded a ClockSync app, and added the NTP server as time.windows.com on port 123 and synced it, but there is still about a noticeable 1.5-2 second difference between my windows. ( I synced my windows as well, that's definitely not the issue).

Can there be some sort of script for this or this there a programatic/non-programatic way to do it?

I am not able to figure out another way, though this might be very simple. I need millisecond precision of sync between the android clock and my windows clock.

1. How do I calculate the difference between my android clock and the windows clock with millisecond precision? I thought there would be some sort of option in eclipse in the android sdk ( I put it on USB debugging mode) but I can't find one.

I can ofcourse programatically capture the time in android and match it with windows but that is good only for second precision, I need millisecond precision.

Any ideas? Programming or otherwise.

Any help is much appreciated.

I have -

Windows 7/XP.

Android 4.0.

Comment: If you're seeing that much of a difference then the NTP is broken on one of them.

Comment: Yeah, I figured the NTP wasn't working on one of them. I tried changing NTP servers- 4-5 different actually, but didn't work and my best guess says, the android is the one with the problem. Hence, the question, do you have a fix for this?

Comment: Sorry, if I had a fix I would have posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

WIndows NTP implementation does not promise accuracy greater than +-2 seconds.  I suggest you find a 3rd party NTP server for windows and use that instead.

Comment: I did try that. I used the nist server and a couple of other servers as well. The same problem persists. I have tried different combinations of phones, NTP servers and even laptops. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: I'm actually investigating NTP implementations myself for android.

You know for the second part of the question, you could always just broadcast System.currentTimeMillis() using java on your PC, and receive it on the phone to do a comparison.  LAN delays shouldn't be greater than 10ms.

Comment: tell me if you can get a sync upto millisecond precision without rooting the phone!

Comment: I eventually just wrote my own server to handle this.  I used my own protocol too.  A bad solution but I needed to move on to other things.

Comment: Wow. I ended up mending my technique as well of how to identify the timestamp. (otherwise i would have simply matched against windows)..had to make a full workaround!

Comment: I need a solution to this, I am stuck trying to debug react native app using react-native-debugger.